# How to filter rows only when all conditions are met in R

Tags: r, filter, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to remove rows from a table of survey response data. I want to remove rows only where all my specified conditions are met. For example, if three columns contain NA then I want to remove the whole row. But if only one or two of those same columns contains NA that is acceptable.

I haven't managed to use filter to achieve this. If I use the code below then it removes the row if any NA's exist as opposed to all the

```r
 df <- filter(df, 
              is.na(Q1) == FALSE & 
              is.na(Q2) == FALSE &
              is.na(Q3) == FALSE)
```

So if we have a df like below I'd only want to remove row #2:

```r
rowid    Q1      Q2     Q3
1        1       3      2
2        NA      NA     NA
3        NA      1      0
4        1       NA     2
5        1       1      NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to use `filter_at` and specify `any_vars` with the condition check for any non-NA elements in a row

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     filter_at(vars(starts_with("Q")), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
#  rowid Q1 Q2 Q3
#1     1  1  3  2
#2     3 NA  1  0
#3     4  1 NA  2
#4     5  1  1 NA
```

As the OP requested specifically (in the comments) for `all_vars`

```
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with('Q')), all_vars(is.na(.))) %>% 
  anti_join(df, ., by = 'rowid')
```

---

Or with `rowSums` from `base R`

```
df[ rowSums(!is.na(df[-1])) != 0,]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(rowid = 1:5, Q1 = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), Q2 = c(3L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L), Q3 = c(2L, NA, 0L, 2L, NA)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: @Bradford Can you edit the post to specify that you would like solution with `all_vars`

Comment: filter_at() with any_vars works great for this. Thanks. I incorrectly presumed that all_vars would get rid of rows that had had NA values for all cells in the specified columns.

Comment: @Bradford  Yes, I upddated with `all_vars`.  It would be great, if you can update your post requesting `all_vars` solution